# Оффтопиком ли будет вопрос-конкурс на создание компьютерной игры для веб браузера?

Tags: обсуждение

Хочу опять задать странный вопрос, если это по Вашему мнению оффтопик - воздержусь.

Вопрос такого характера - Конкурс на создание компьютерной игры для веб браузера

условия:

- наличие запускаемого примера, отсутствие внешних ресурсов.
- наличие геймплея.
- условия победы, ну и техническая возможность выиграть.

Победитель тот, кто набрал больше всего голосов.

Comment: Игра должна запускаться в сниппете? Какие требования к коду? Возможность использования библиотек?

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде это понятно из п1, условие про зависимости можно конечно убрать, если это увеличит кол-во ответов, ведь тут главное - идея

Comment: А, тьфу, я невнимательный. Только про запускаемый пример обратил внимание. А картинки как - они тоже внешние ресурсы?

Comment: @Qwertiy предлагаю остановиться на emoji в качестве картинок =), хотя это конечно все не важно

Comment: _техническая возможность выиграть_, - То есть всякие тетрисы-змейки и т.п. сразу не подходят?

Comment: @Yaant почему же, придумайте условие победы, например кол-во очков, длина змеи

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, формат конкурса - чтобы весь код был в сниппете ответа или внешние ресурсы привлекать тоже можно?

Comment: @Kromster я вроде написал про отсутствие внешних ресурсов, однако мне кажется это не самое главное, можно было бы от этого отказаться

Comment: Я понимаю кто-то против конкурса, но сам то этот вопрос чем плох?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Лично мне кажется, что голоса на мете играют иную роль. Они не отражают качество вопроса, а выражают мнение сообщества по поводу идеи, которая в нём заложена.

Comment: @nomnoms12 строго говоря у стрелочек есть всплывающая подсказка

Comment: @nomnoms12, возможно, но не всегда, поэтому спорно. Лучше отвечать - вот голоса на ответе точно согласие и несогласие означают.

Comment: @Qwertiy в любом случае я склонен предполагать что тенденция не изменится. будем продолжать просматривать вопросы про потерю контекста и про верстку котиков

Comment: Лично мне и существование код-гольфа тоже не нравится, например

Answer (score 7):

Учитывая, что код-гольф разрешили, видимо не оффтопик. Но все равно, в таком виде идея соревнования мне не нравится, из-за вот этой части: "Победитель тот, кто набрал больше всего голосов". Stackoverflow - плохая платформа для определения победителей голосованием; при таком подходе те, кто раньше опубликовал ответ, имеют преимущество, так как голосовать можно сразу после публикации ответа. Чтобы проводить подобное соревнование, нужна специальная платформа, которая позволит выделить два этапа: предварительное формирование списка участников и непосредственно голосование (которое все участники начинают с нулевым количеством голосов). Что-то аналогичное выборам модераторов. Либо придумать другой способ определения победителей.

Кроме того, я надеюсь, что ваши условия - это только черновик, так как при такой формулировке ("создать любую игру для браузера") можно просто отправить на конкурс ранее разработанный проект. Нужна определенная тематика и какие-то особые ограничения, чтобы вынудить создавать решение именно с нуля.

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос будет "слишком общим" и не иметь "объективно верного ответа", т.е. не соответствовать тематике ruSO.

Так же он создаст плохой прецедент - имея 1 модератора в поддержке, вы будете долго отбиваться от голосов за закрытие и драмы на Мете.

Comment: Эм.. Как бы такие вопросы уже были...

Comment: @Qwertiy угу вроде этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924210/

Answer (score 1):

Соревнования не являются оффтопиком. Критерий по числу голосов - тоже нормально, хотя, возможно, стоит определиться со сроками соревнования.

Точно надо подетальнее продумать условия соревнования.

Comment: это сложный вопрос, я бы попытался оценить оригинальность идеи или качество реализации