# Новогодний конкурс узаконен

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, правила, соревнование

Этот вопрос создан с информационной целью - донести мысль, что [Новогодний конкурс 2020 года](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1061127/15479) является онтопиком сайта.

Некоторые участники не оценили этот конкурс, считая его оффтопиком. Кто-то пытался закрыть как "Слишком общий". И это немного странно, учитывая что точно такой же [конкурс был и в прошлом году](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924210/15479).

Даже больше, у нас есть специальные метки [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [code-golf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). И напомню, что [код-гольф у нас разрешён](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2933/15479).

Так что просим:

- Не стоит закрывать такие вопросы (учитывая, что подобный конкурс лишь раз в год).
- Не стоит ставить тревоги на таких вопросах (тревоги не для этого нужны).

Ну и милости просим, вы всегда можете поучаствовать в конкурсе или предложить награду   (◕‿◕)

Comment: А я бы приветствовал подобные конкурсы, инициируемые любым участником, в любом количестве и по любому поводу (можно и без повода)

Comment: @avp вы всегда можете сами инициировать конкурс/соревнование (;

Comment: Так донесите мысль, что это онтопик. Укажите на пункты правил хотя бы. Ну или там на пункт правил, что все что заявляется модератором как онтопик, автоматически им становится.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan я же привёл ссылки на уже принятые решения сообщество в отношении того же гольфа и соревнований. Я, честно говоря, не понимаю, что ещё требуется.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan ну сейчас развернется жаркая дискуссия на счет онтопика. Когда я приглашаю прокачать мозги и повеселиться вместе, делая творческую работу, за одно научиться чему-то новому, анализируя работы других участников или просто получить эстетическое удовольствие, - люди отвечают : У МЕНЯ НЕТ ВРЕМЕНИ!  А вот жарко поспорить на канцелярские темы, это завсегда пожалуйста :=)

Comment: Так я не против конкурса. Просто если мы создадим сейчас прецедент, что достаточно объявить (не спрашивая остальных участников) любой офтопичный вопрос как онтопик, то как потом будем останавливать злоупотребления?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan злоупотребления в чём? Я в целом поддерживаю avp в этом вопросе (как участник). Чем больше конкурсов/соревнований, тем лучше.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica код-гольфы можно хоть с какой-то натяжкой вписать в базу знаний, ибо они могут ответить на вопросы вроде «на каком языке получится более компактный код» (полезность таких знаний, впрочем, сомнительна). А здесь — ничего, лишь мешанина из «рекомендаций».

Comment: @Alexandr_TT не занимаюсь и не собираюсь заниматься, не волнуйтесь.

Comment: Формулировка поста - ужасна. Вы делаете большое заявление и ничем его по сути не подкрепляете кроме отсылки на прошлый сходный опыт. Выглядит как "Я так сказал, значит так и будет. Точка". Хорошо что внизу АК высказался, что узаконен он мод.составом.

Answer (score 11):

#### Конкурсы на Stack Overflow

У конкурсов в нашем сообществе богатая история: мы проводили различные конкурсы практически с первого дня существования сайта, причем как на Мете, так и на основном сайте, проводили и сами, и в партнерстве с другими сообществами. На наш взгляд, сами по себе конкурсы — это здорово.

Движок и миссия Stack Overflow накладывает свои ограничения на конкурс, об этом стоит помнить при планировании. Например, на основном сайте, конкурсный вопрос не должен выходить за рамки правил сайта и механик движка. На мой взгляд, запустить конкурс правильно совершенно не сложно, главное — было бы желание! Если вы хотите провести конкурс и считаете, что вам нужна какая-либо помощь, пожалуйста, напишите [мне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile) или [модераторам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) об этом! Мы обязательно поможем оформить конкурс (а в некоторых случаях поможем с памятными призами победителям).

#### «Новогодний конкурс узаконен»

В публикации «[Теория модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/6)» рассказано про устройство Stack Overflow:

- Все участники модерируют сайт. Привилегии модерации зависят от текущей репутации участника.
- В случае исключительных ситуаций модерации, участникам ассистируют модераторы.
- При необходимости, исключительные ситуации рассматриваются на Мете.

Формулировка «Новогодний конкурс узаконен» — досадное стечение обстоятельств. Модераторы единолично по дизайну сайта не создают «законы» и не могут чего–либо «узаконивать». Участники обсуждают вопросы модерации вместе, в том числе вопрос [тематики сайта](/help/on-topic), а при необходимости, в обсуждениях принимают участие сотрудники компании (управляющие сообществами). [Я писал про это детально в ранее.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7425/6)

На мой взгляд, этот вопрос следует читать примерно так:

> Здравствуйте, дорогие коллеги! Поздравляем вас с Новым Годом! Чтобы скоротать вечера длинных выходных, пожалуйста, примите участие в новогоднем конкурсе! Изобретательность и нестандартный подход к решению — хорошая заявка на победу! Будем рады вашим ответам =)

Comment: мне кажется, вы указываете прямую дорогу к закрытию темы по бюрократическим мотивам. В конце концов свяжитесь с сотрудниками компании, дайте им ссылки на  конкурс НГ 2018, 2019 года пусть посмотрят какие там есть яркие, сильные работы пообсуждайте, подумайте, как поддержать инициативу, которая идёт снизу.  В условиях, когда налицо явное неприятие и протестное голосование всего, что идёт сверху я думаю ваши предложения обречены на провал.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Если честно, я не до конца понимаю, о чем вы. Решения сверху нет, как и закрытие темы. Я в частности, как и мои коллеги в общем, за конкурсы =)

Comment: Вопрос по расширению рамок проведения конкурса НГ, по не соблюдению формальных правил проведения конкурсов, прочитайте пожалуйста, мои мысли на эту тему, что будет с конкурсом НГ, если формально соблюдать правила [проведения конкурсов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9997/28748) Вам не надо, чтобы конкурс был яркий, праздничный? Мне наверное тоже уже не надо этого, зачем мне тратить столько времени, сил, нервов, чтобы доказывать очевидное, - что конкурс проведенный по правилам движка, не будет творческим конкурсом.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Все, что требуется от вопроса–конкурса — это то, чтобы он был вопросом и к нему можно было дать ответы, среди которых формально можно выбрать лучший. Под этот формат можно практически все подвести, включая творческие вопросы =) Например, «как создать елочку, которая меньше / больше / более быстро / меньше кода / и тд»

Comment: и всегда найдутся люди при такой раскладке, которые будут беспокоить модераторов тревогами, на тему закрытия вопроса `как слишком общий` потому что невозможно оговорить в вопросе всё, что люди могли бы творчески придумать, сделать в своих ответах.   Почему не устраивает формулировка не ограничивающая людей в их творчестве -  "Картинка может быть любая, анимация может быть любой, требование лишь одно, - сюжет и персонажи должны быть Новогодними" Ещё раз скажу, какое примите решение, такое и будет, я просто приму к сведению. А на результаты посмотрим в следующем году.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Такие тревоги часто на разные вопросы приходят. Тут самое главное — нам всем понимать, что к чему. И модераторы, и сотрудники, и многие участники за конкурсы. Как я написал в ответе, конкурсы мы проводили с первого дня существования сайта и будем далее проводить. Решение было принято еще при создании сайта =)

Answer (score 9):

Пожалуй, выскажу и своё мнение.

Эти конкурсы никогда не были запрещены. Они уже проводились в прошлом году и оба раза были довольно позитивно приняты сообществом, о чём однозначно говорит их рейтинг +66 -2 и +66 -0. Они в целом более-менее вписываются в обсуждение соревнований, т. е. они уже обсуждались.

Тем не менее 20 декабря на вопрос поставили первую тревогу. Потом 4 января другой пользователь поставил ещё 4 тревоги (последовательно). Я считаю правильным в такой ситуации выйти и публично заявить, что вопрос - онтопик. **Это заявление не является изменением тематики, оно лишь явно описывает конкретный случай в соответствии с уже имеющейся тематикой.** Если её хочется поменять - это вполне можно обсудить.

Далее, что касается тревог. Тревоги с текстом *"вопрос слишком общий"* вообще не должны ставиться как кастомные тревоги модераторам. Для этого есть очереди закрытия. Да, вопрос с вознаграждением нельзя закрыть без участия модератора, тем не менее, надо было либо пошевелиться раньше, либо подождать завершения конкурса. К тому же, судя по таймлайну, тревоги ставились уже после того, как конкурс завершился.

Comment: Голосовать за закрытие можно не чаще примерно раза в две недели. Если голос сгорел в конкурсе — только тревоги и остаются.

Comment: @andreymal, голос сгорает только по таймауту, конкурс не отменяет голоса, насколько я помню.

Comment: Таймаут случится до окончания конкурса, так что он всё равно сгорел

Answer (score 6):

> Этот вопрос создан с информационной целью - донести мысль, что Новогодний конкурс 2020 года является онтопиком сайта.

Кто это сказал? Администрация, коллектив модераторов или вы лично? На каком основании изменения тематики объявляются на мете по факту, а не выносятся на предварительное обсуждение? Объявление диктатуры, кажется, не очень хороший способ празднования Нового Года? Напоминаю, еще недавно мы обсуждали соревнования ([Оффтопиком ли будет вопрос-конкурс на создание компьютерной игры для веб браузера?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9472/%D0%9E%D1%84%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80?rq=1)), и при этом не наблюдалось однозначного решения сообщества "разрешить".

> Некоторые участники не оценили этот конкурс, считая его оффтопиком. Кто-то пытался закрыть как "Слишком общий". И это немного странно, учитывая что точно такой же конкурс был и в прошлом году.

Что в этом странного? Участники имеют право выразить свое мнение, тем более что формально, если сопоставить вопрос с требованиями справки, он действительно подпадает под несколько причин закрытия. Существование незакрытых старых вопросов, не соответствующих правилам, не оправдывает задание новых. У нас полно старого незакрытого мусора типа "Помогите не работает Skype" висит незакрытым и удаляется духом только через год, просто потому что немногие заходят в метку, или потому что очереди перегружены.

> Даже больше, у нас есть специальная меткм соревнование и code-golf. И напомню, что код-гольф у нас разрешён.

Код-гольф, хоть и оторван от практики, существенно отличается от обсуждаемого конкурса, наличием четко сформулированного задания и критериев победы. "[Реализовать наиболее короткий алгоритм выборки комбинаций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581668/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9)" - вполне четкая и конкретная задача, почти по теме, если смотреть формально. Не вижу, как это дает основание считать обсуждаемый конкурс онтопиком.

> Так что просим:
>
> - Не стоит закрывать такие вопросы (учитывая, что подобный конкурс лишь раз в год).
> - Не стоит ставить тревоги на таких вопросах (тревоги не для этого нужны)

ОК. Это не выглядит невыполнимой просьбой. Не исполнять какую-либо сложную обязанность, вроде определения соответствия вопросов правилам, всегда легко и приятно.

> Ну и милости просим, вы всегда можете поучаствовать в конкурсе или предложить награду (◕‿◕)

Спасибо. Я не имею отношения к веб-дизайну и графике, поэтому не собирался участвовать в конкурсе, как и не имею сильной позиции против него. Моя основная претензия к конкурсу, это то, что он слишком расплывчатый, нет определенных условий и критериев победы. Даже и сами формулировки непонятны:

> Кроме тегов включенных в вопрос, допускается использовать ответы с дополнительными тегами.

Что в данном случае подразумевается под тегами? HTML Tags? Или метки на сайте? В ответах и веб-дизайн, и консольная графика на С++, что заставляет склониться ко второму варианту. Правда, выглядит как гонка лыжника со сноубордистом.

На мой взгляд, конкурс должен быть четко сформулирован, иметь конкретную (сложную, но достаточно открытую для творческих решений) задачу, определять правила и критерий победы (**не** рейтинг ответа - см обсуждение по ссылке выше). У нас сайт программистов, а не детский сад, соревнование должно быть спортивным. Если кто-то хочет проводить конкурсы с менее четкими условиями, я не имею сильной позиции против. Пусть это будет, но в порядке исключения, а не правила. Не нужно, пожалуйста, махать перед сообществом флагом с надписью "Это насильно сделано онтопиком" - это неприятно.

Comment: Вы не находите, что термин "изменение тематики сайта" -- это как-то слишком громко для 1 (прописью: одной) темы раз в год? В остальном же я так понял позицию: не участвую сам, не особо одобряю, но не мешаю людям отпраздновать и повеселиться: не закрываю, просто прохожу мимо. Это верное обобщение поста?

Comment: @AK Если эта одна тема сильно отличается от того, что считалось тематикой до этого, не думаю. Кроме того, у Suvitruf именно "является онтопиком", а не "включен в порядке исключения". Громкое заявление в ответ на громкое заявление. Да, обобщение верное.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight я не силён в подобных постах. Может стоит перефразировать)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight `Что в данном случае подразумевается под тегами? HTML Tags? Или метки на сайте?` справедливости ради посмотрите Enso, хоть левую панель, хоть страницу с заголовком [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)  У нас при локализации  вместо общеупотребительного `тег` перевели, как `Метка` могли и по другому перевести, значений у этого англ. слова очень много. Так стоило ли включать это в обоснование своей позиции?

Answer (score 6):

Коллеги, чувствую необходимость высказаться — больше из роли модератора.

Тем кому нужны подробности о хронологии событий могу пояснить следующее.

В простых случаях решение принимается модератором единолично, в случае затруднений мы советуемся друг с другом и принимаем решение коллегиально. Ну, тем составом, который в данный момент времени онлайн, хотя если вопрос сложный — то ждём остальных, чтобы учесть больше мнений при принятии голосов.

В конкретно этом случае вопрос обсуждался коллегиально, а не единолично, но не полным составом. С одной стороны ждать пока все соберутся с новогодних каникул и выскажутся — уже поезд уйдёт и вопрос потеряет актуальность, с другой стороны понимания, как конкретно обработать флаги (их, кажется два было, первый отклонили быстро, а над вторым уже задумались, не упускаем ли мы чего) не было, поэтому советовались.

У меня позиция сводилась к следующим пунктам:

- я лично не против новогодних конкурсов — и считаю, что подобные конкурсы идут на благо сайта. уж последнее что мне хотелось — это выйти и сказать "знаете, по строгим правилам эти конкурсы нужно закрыть".
- я считал, что если провести опрос среди участников, то большинство выскажется за то, чтобы для подобных НГ конкурсов будет сделано небольшое исключение и не закрывать.
- я понимал, что обязательно наберётся некоторое меньшинство участников, которые считают что буква правил является абсолютным приоритетом (соблюдать правила — хорошая привычка), уж как минимум — те, кто уже подали флаги.

Поэтому я предложил формально создать новое правило, новую традицию. Чтобы уже на будущий год модсостав мог апеллировать к формальному правилу.

> Я помню как-то давно обсуждал с ВладД о том, какие локальные правила
>   возможны для сайтов и тогда не нашёл ни одного примера, а вот недавно
>   [подкинули](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341597/348096) как раз
>   ссылку на метамету и я думаю, что вот этот НГ конкурс -- очень удачный
>   пример таких локальных правил, традиций.

Что ещё вошло в предложение? Я говорил о том, что нужно это оформить отдельной темой на мете: есть некоторое число ситуаций, когда участники сами не хотят идти на мету и обсуждать вопрос, но подают тревогу -- и это как раз такой случай, мне казалось важным не просто отклонить или принять тревогу, но сделать решение публичным.

И мне очень не хотелось затягивать вопрос. Недавно, PashaPash упрекал, что вопрос с домашками сильно забюрократизировался и чтобы решить его нужно приложить очень много излишних [на его взгляд] усилий. И мне стыдно было за эту волокиту, хотя сам против неё высказывался — ну, там решение не только от меня зависело. И мне не нравилось, что скорее всего решить для конкурса текущего года голосованием активистов меты вряд ли получится. (Либо будет короткий срок голосования, либо пройдут праздники, либо мало участников проголосуют, а у нас на мете сами знаете, не так уж и много активистов)

Поэтому я и предложил написать, что давайте на текущий год (раз уж конкурс в разгаре) считать, что этот год конкурс легален, а на следующий раз обсудим с сообществом, чтобы уже точно иметь качественное обоснование не/легальности. (К декабрю-то уж точно  наголосует достаточный кворум, верно?)

Мнения (помимо моего) высказывались разные, в том числе и за то, что подобные НГ конкурсы априори норм. Или это уже после было? Если надо могу поднять хронологию и уточнить, но точно уверен, что именно моё решение было взято за основу в основных чертах. Ну, я по крайней мере ощущаю это коллегиальное решение в основном как своё, так что если кому нужно персонализировать обратно ответственность, то я уж точно буду в числе основных лиц, принимавших решение.

А вот оформлять на мете тему вызвался Андрей, который постарался в максимально нейтральных формулировках высказать итоговое решение.

Я видел мнения, что он написал нехорошо, но на мой взгляд он постарался максимально сгладить острые углы, в том числе и те, которые я не заметил. Мне его текст в целом понравился, сам бы я написал иначе, но как по мне вышло весьма хорошо.

В первую очередь я бы хотел обратиться к тем, кто увидел в этих формулировках то, что модераторы самовольно создают правила. Нет! Считаю (и я высказывался в чате тем, что кто опасался подобного поворота), что сила позиции модератора как раз в том, чтобы держаться за правила. И снаружи не особо видно, кто и как из модераторов высказывается по тем или иным вопросам всегда рекомендую держаться этой позиции как самой выигрышной.

Если кто-то готов упрекнуть Андрея за неудачные формулировки, упрекните и меня, как перечитавшего пост, я не увидел ничего плохого в формулировках.

Во вторых, я готов лично принести извинения, что не придумал более идеальное решение вопроса: чтобы и публично, и проголосовать всем и чтобы текущий конкурс не загубили бы (Ну вот реально, могли же на будущий год отбить охоту проводить подобное? Да я и сейчас не знаю, не отбили ли). Вероятно, можно было бы просто спихнуть ответственность на кого-то другого, но я не считаю такое поведение достойным. Я не ангел с крыльями, иногда у меня бывают не самые лучшие решения.

Давайте я попробую ещё раз объяснить свою позицию:

> Ну или там ... все что заявляется модератором как онтопик, автоматически им становится

Нет такого пункта в правилах. Модератор руководствуется правилами и придерживается сложившегося на мете общественного консенсуса.

В данном случае Андрей также постарался логически обосновать своё видение, сославшись на прошлый год (читай: уже сложившиеся традиции, пусть пока и не зафиксированные в виде правил), на аналогии, которые показались уместными. Важным для меня и Андрея был пункт о публичности, мы приходили как модераторы считавшими прозрачность модерирования хорошим тоном. На вопросе стоит метка "обсуждение", которая показывает, что мы ожидали обратной реакции и не только от участников, которые ставили флаги, а общего обсуждения.

> Просто если мы создадим сейчас прецедент, что достаточно объявить (не спрашивая остальных участников)

Такого прецедента не было на мете ранее и не создалось сегодня. И я думаю, что и в будущем не возникнет. Если у вас есть подобные опасения — то я могу заверить, что с моей стороны таких мыслей не возникает.

Надеюсь, подобного пояснения достаточно по поводу прошлого и настоящего?

Если да, то предлагаю следующий роадмап на будущее:

- предлагаю считать, что обсуждение НГ конкурса 2019 — 2020 года закрыто: в конце концов конкурс уже прошёл, как прошли и новогодние праздники. "Дорога ложка к обеду":
- предлагаю в отдельной теме всё же определиться что нам делать с последующими такими конкурсами, как минимум — с конкурсом 2020 — 2021 года, чтобы участники на мете могли обсудить, стоит ли таким конкурсам были или стоит их закрывать как оффтопичные

Comment: @A K Да, практически отбили желание проводить конкурсы НГ, вы верно догадались. С самого начала конкурса посыпались негативные комментарии, которые активно заплюсовывались. На мои ответные комментарии в защиту конкурса было глухое молчание. Я не мог понять, что происходит в этом году, почему прошлогодний конкурс был принят на Ура, а в этом году такая негативная реакция. Решил, что за этот год мир изменился не в лучшую сторону и с этим ничего не поделаешь.

Comment: @A K Модераторы могут подтвердить, я не обращался за помощью, не жаловался, не рассылал тревоги и для меня было приятной неожиданность открытие темы обсуждения, узаконивания конкурса НГ.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT вот теперь вы лишние подозрения на себя навлекли (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica по большому счету мне сейчас уже всё равно.  Праздничное настроение было капитально испорчено Я столько сил вложил в подготовку, проведение конкурса. Когда это всё началось, я даже не стал опубликовывать новые готовые работы в конкурсе НГ.   В чате я опубликовывал только приглашения к участию в конкурсе и Было лишь одно сообщение ни к кому конкретно не адресованное с недоумением, - почему в этом году такая неактивность при огромном количестве просмотров `2k` за три дня с открытия конкурса.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT всё же, тех, кто был за конкурс, и кто получил от него удовольствие, было больше. И это радует.

Comment: В моем ответе есть некоторая доля иронии. Нет необходимости извиняться, так как я не обвиняю на полном серьезе модераторов, что вы сделали что-то плохое. Основной вопрос, который я хотел поднять - качество соревнований. Когда кто-то сыплет тревогами, можно воспринять это как "хочет испортить праздник", а можно - как указание на некие проблемы. Не надо обсуждать "запретить или нет конкурсы", обсуждайте, как сделать хороший конкурс, по поводу которого не надо будет воевать.

Comment: @A K А что мешает провести обсуждение здесь. Люди чётко высказали свою позицию, может добавят, что-то ещё. Как решат, так и будет, лично я приму к сведению любое решение. . Перенос в другой топик, затянет, забюрократизирует решение, как вопрос с домашками. Время посчитают много, целый год и в конце следующего года будет точно такая же картина маслом.  Да и решений то всего два, - проводим по правилам и просто убиваем конкурс НГ (см. в моем ответе [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9997/28748)) или даём ему свободу в качестве исключения.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Ничего не мешает, я просто считаю, что разные темы должны быть оформлены отдельно. Для меня логично здесь оставить обсуждение сложившейся ситуации (если кому будет что добавить), а обсуждение на следующий год оформить отдельно. Но в общем-то мне этот момент не сильно принципиален.

Answer (score 1):

Негативная реакция некоторых участников на текущий конкурс НГ.

Я за соблюдение правил обоими руками.  Прекрасно понимаю, что несоблюдение правил превратит наш сайт  в помойку.
Но взгляните на ситуацию с другой стороны, подойдем к конкурсу НГ с точки зрения существующих правил и предъявленных претензий на их основании.

*Вопрос слишком общий*
*Условия проведения конкурса не чётко определены*
*По каждому пункту из перечня рекомендуемых объектов анимации нужно проводить отдельный конкурс*
*Широкий набор меток с допускаемым его расширением*

Да, согласен, с точки зрения правил сплошной неформат.

Хочется только спросить, - неужели Вам действительно хочется уныло, по правилам встречать единственный в году, объединяющий всех праздник?

Формулируя такие широкие условия проведения конкурса, я стремился вовлечь в него, как можно больше участников, создать творческую атмосферу. Каждый год, мне нисколько не жалко отдавать максимально возможное вознаграждение за проведение НГ конкурса.
Я хочу, чтобы мы узнавали при проведение такого конкурса  новые имена, увидели яркие творческие работы, глядя на которые, у многих бы загоралось желание сделать в будущем, что-то подобное.

Разве возможно такое при проведении конкурса  по заформализованным правилам или отвечая на примитивные, ленивые вопросы новичков сайта, которым лень открыть первые страницы, соответствующих учебников.

Comment: Сказано идеально! Вот это пожелание, которое вы раскритиковали следовало вообще пометить "Недружелюбный или враждебный" (будь я модератором я бы его удалил,  еще бы отправил "Это сообщение касается вашей учетной записи" и впаял бы его автору suspension ). **_А новогодний конкурс был шикарный :) !_** Главное мне за день до этого конкурса пришла идея сделать что-то подобное. Я тоже думаю хоть на Новый Год то можно людям дать _немного_ нарушить правила!

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica "будь я модератором я бы его удалил, еще бы отправил 'Это сообщение касается вашей учетной записи' и впаял бы его автору suspension" Поэтому вы и не модератор ^_^". Сообщение не нарушает правил. Там, по большей части, лишь голые факты, плюс немного иронии в конце.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Согласен, но все таки последняя строчка это что-то...

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica да, может кому-то испортить настроение, не спорю. Но, тем не менее, это не является оскорблением/выпадом в адрес других участников.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Приму к сведению.

Answer (score 1):

> Я не имею отношения к веб-дизайну и графике, поэтому не собирался
>   участвовать в конкурсе, как и не имею сильной позиции против него. Моя
>   основная претензия к конкурсу, это то, что он слишком расплывчатый,
>   нет определенных условий и критериев победы. Даже и сами формулировки
>   непонятны:

Хорошо, давайте поразмыслим немного об жёстких, не расплывчатых условиях проведения конкурса.

Когда писались  правила проведения обычного конкурса, то подразумевалось, что организатор конкурса, не получив решения в обычных ответах, готов пожертвовать, рискнуть своей репой и открыть конкурс, чтобы привлечь внимание и может быть всё таки получить правильный ответ. Поэтому и требования в вопросе и к решению должны быть очень чёткими.

Вы настаиваете на соблюдении таких правил проведения конкурса.

Тогда, в этом случае, организатор конкурса должен дать например:

1. Изображение новогодней ёлочки и нельзя использовать другую ёлку
2. Использовать чёткую формулировку, описывающую, допустим анимации огней на ёлке. Они должны бежать сверху-вниз. Анимация звезды, для отвечающего уже оффтопик.
3. Привести код своей попытки, где у него якобы не получилось это сделать.
4. Оговорить 2-3 тега (метки) допустим CSS и JS

Допустим я предпочитаю делать анимации в SVG, значит я уже за бортом конкурса и не приму участие в конкурсе?

А кто-то может захочет сделать анимацию падающих снежинок или анимацию Деда Мороза со снегурочкой, зайчиков там всяких, белочек и других новогодних персонажей? Тоже за бортом конкурса?

Объединение двух пунктов объектов анимации или тем более уже весь этот далеко не полный список, уже попадает под определение `слишком общий вопрос, на который невозможно дать чёткий, однозначный ответ`

А кто-то хочет блеснуть в анимации фразы **С Новым Годом!**

У кого-то лучше всего получаются фейерверки, значит тоже за бортом конкурса?

Хорошо, попробуйте провести такой конкурс по чётко оговоренному, не `расплывчатому` заданию. Не ошибусь сильно, если участников будет от одного до трех и участие будет не ради творчества, а желания срубить репу. Качество будет тоже соответственное, ведь даже в случае непринятия ни одного из ответов система распределит её половину между ответившими участниками. И люди об этом знают :)

Вы этого хотите? Именно такого проведения Новогоднего конкурса?

**Теперь о чётких критериях победителя**

Вообще-то негласное правило, - кто платит, тот и заказывает музыку (выбирает ответ)

Но ни справедливости, ни возмущения насчет неправильного выбора победителя, однако не наблюдалось, ни в конкурсах 2018 года (призы выдавались 4 раза, разными спонсорами ) ни в 2019 году (призы выдавались 2 раза) Так, как были выбраны, действительно самые сильные, самые зрелищные работы.

Поэтому я считаю, что формулировка, выбранная в этом году для проведения конкурса НГ:

> Картинка может быть любая, анимация может быть любой, требование лишь
>   одно, - сюжет и персонажи должны быть Новогодними.

Наиболее подходит к такому конкурсу и позволит проявить  любому участнику свои знания  и полёт фантазии.

Можно порассуждать также, над расширением тегов (меток) больше 5-ти для привлечения бОльшего количества участников, чтобы конкурс НГ действительно стал общим для всех, у кого есть желание и возможности показать свои работы.

Можно обсудить варианты параллельного проведения нескольких конкурсов НГ по разному набору меток. Но это вряд ли удастся, так как очень трудно раскачать, зажечь большое количество людей по разным меткам.

Поэтому в 2019 году, как и в 2018 году была включена фраза в условия проведения конкурса:

> Кроме тегов включенных в вопрос, допускается использовать ответы с
>   дополнительными тегами.

Comment: С  моей точки зрения есть несколько типов конкурса, если даже исключить "обычные" конкурсы на платформе. Просто давайте договоримся, что есть тип конкурса как "кодгольф" и такой тип конкурса как "праздничный". И пусть эти фестивальные конкурсы идут по менее строгим правилам, вон [хорошо же сказал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9969/213987): "соревнование в популярности". Я лично всегда на конкурсах просто запускаю скрипты и ставлю плюсики всему, что мне понравилось. Там обычно и так отмечаются участники, которым и так репу девать некуда, чисто ради самого участия.

Comment: В прошлом году я подала идею, которую тебе удалось очень здорово воплотить в жизнь! Конкурс зашел на "Ура"! В этом году все оказалось немножко иначе (не так как нам хотелось)! У многих не было свободного времени и в праздники (в  том числе и у меня). И как мне кажется, некоторые, потеряли интерес! Так происходит со всем что уже не ново ... приелось! Так может быть не стоит создавать дополнительные обсуждения по данной теме чтобы не вызвать, и вовсе, негативных эмоций у большинства?!

Comment: Конкурс изжил себя. Либо, действительно, нужны более конкретные условия.

Comment: @HamSter Ты права, пока ничего больше не хочется. Год большой срок, много чего может измениться и не в лучшую сторону. Доживем, посмотрим, какое будет настроение у людей.

Comment: Вот именно! Через год видно будет! Если вопрос и закроют (думаю не удалят) ответы останутся!