# Как править вопрос на мете?

Tags: поддержка, правки

[Вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9961/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD?cb=1). Как он отредактировал вопрос, у меня красная плашка выпрыгивает, которая запрещает это делать:

[image: Редакция]
[image: запрет]

Но как они могут быть запрещены, если вот - человек отредактировал. Тогда уж нужно текст запрета менять, ведь правки запрещены, но не для всех. Думаю, нужно писать условие разблокировки такой возможности.

Comment: Нужно 2 000 репутации.

Comment: @AK тогда нужно добавить условие в плашку. Она неправдива.

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar а что не так? 2000 репы дают возможность вносить прямые правки, а правки-предложения как были запрещены, так и остаются.

Comment: Она правдива, просто непонятна. Речь о том, что на мете нет механизма предложенных правок, общие сообщения тут по сути не при чем.

Comment: А, ну да. Думал, что правки и правки-предложения - одно и то же. Тогда нужно хоть как-то намекнуть, что при достижении 2000 репутации правки делать можно.